# Error : No operator "<<" matches these operands

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and I am having problems understanding why I am getting this error. The error message that I am receiving is "No operator '<<' matches these operands" This is the coding that I have where the error is occurring

```
#include "LList.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    LList a;

    a.push_back(  "30" );
    a.push_front( "20" );
    a.push_back(  "40" );
    a.push_front( "10" );
    a.push_back(  "50" );

    cout << "list a:\n" << a << '\n';

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: The person who wrote `LList.h` for you didn't implement printing.

Answer (score 8):

You need to overload the `operator <<` for LList. To do that implement the following:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const LList& llist)
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much. that cleared up my error. something as simple as that. would this matter if i were put that line of code in the LList.h file or in this current file?

Comment: I said you need to **implement it** that means simply putting that line will not fix anything. You need to use LList's interface to implement the logic to print it into an output stream.

Comment: If you could, would it be possible if you could help me out with that? I've been trying to think of what to put inside of that, but I can't seem to come up with anything